# Virtual memory - paging - establishing location

Tags: memory, memory-management, hex, paging

A certain computer provides its users with a virtual memory space of 2^24 words. Computer has 2^18 words of physical memory. The virtual memory is implemented by paging, and the page size is 256 words. A user program generates the virtual address 24A72E (HEX). Explain how the system established the corresponding physical location...

Answer (score 0):

Logical Page (i.e. the page table entry) = 24a72Ex / 256

That provides a index to a page table entry. That page table entry identifies the physical memory page.

The word offset into the page is is 24a72Ex MOD 256